# Word preceding "of"?

Tags: terminology, phrase-structure

What do you call the word preceding "of"?

> **A** of B

> **the paintings** of Monet

I mean the words "A" and "the paintings" in these examples. I forgot how you call it.

Sorry, we have any academic/specific/grammatical name that refers to those words, like "anaphora". I don't mean they are anaphora, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be called the "head of the noun phrase". In this case the adjectival phrase "of Monet" modifies (describes) the noun "paintings", which heads the entire phrase.

I like to speak about parent-child relationships in grammar, so I'd also call "paintings" the "parent" of the adjectival phrase "of Monet" (or perhaps just of that phrase's head, if you prefer that approach).

Answer (score 1):

> the paintings of Monet

This is not an independent clause but a noun phrase; 'paintings' is the noun.